# Generative model and inference

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I was looking at the hLDA model here:
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2466-hierarchical-topic-models-and-the-nested-chinese-restaurant-process.pdf

I have questions on how the generative model works. What will be the output of the generative model and how is it used in the inference(Gibbs sampling) stage. I am getting mixed up with the generative model and inference part and am not able to distinguish between them.

I am new to this area and any reference articles or papers that can be useful to clear the concept would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

To get a handle on how this type of Bayesian model works, I'd recommend David Blei's original 2003 LDA paper (google scholar "Latent Dirichlet Allocation" and it'll appear near the top). They used variational inference (as opposed to Gibbs sampling) to estimate the "posterior" (which you could call the "best fit solution"), but the principles behind using a generative model are well explained.

In a nutshell, Bayesian topic models work like this: you presume that your data is created by some "generative model". This model describes a probabilistic process for generating data, and has a few unspecified "latent" variables. In a topic model, these variables are the "topics" that you're trying to find. The idea is to find the most probable values for the "topics" given the data at hand.

In Bayesian inference these most probable values for latent variables are known as the "posterior". Strictly speaking, the posterior is actually a probability distribution over possible values for the latent variables, but a common approach is to use the most probable set of values, called "maximum a posteriori" or MAP estimation.

Note that for topic models, what you get is an estimate for the true MAP values. Many of the latent values, perhaps especially those close to zero, are essentially noise, and cannot be taken seriously (except for being close to zero). It's the larger values that are more meaningful.